# Adding MSGraph Authentication to a teams bot generated using yo teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

How do i add authentication to a teams app (bot + Messaging extension) generated using the 'Yo Teams' yeoman generator? I am using typescript and there are no samples out there for auth. Secondly, since the yo teams generator generates a single bot.ts file and the auth for bots are a little different with respect to invoke activity, how do i handle the invoke activity in a msteams bot provisioned with yo teams geenrator?

Comment: Have you looked at the [following](https://mmsharepoint.wordpress.com/2020/07/03/a-microsoft-teams-messaging-extension-with-authentication-and-access-to-microsoft-graph-i/)?

Comment: Yes i have, however, that is for messaging extensions and the same does not apply for bots. Hence reaching out for help on BOTS. It is a little different per this link in the end, they mention about invoke activity being forwarded to the OAuthPrompt? I am not sure i understand this right - https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/bot-call-graph-as-user

Comment: Then you may want to look at one of the other ways. Adding related docs[1 Azure BOT service's oAuthCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-authentication/auth-flow-bot), [2 Teams Auth flow for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-authentication/auth-oauth-card)

Comment: Thank you Dev, i have looked at this, they all state the same. I am still kind of stuck, since the yo man generator scaffolds the entire project into one bot.ts file. So will have to dig in further and check more.

Answer (score 0):

currently messaging extension authentication sample is not available in typescript. You can raise user voice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/).